# CKEditor : Embed Tweets are not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor to write new articles on my site. When I copy an embed code from twitter and paste it in ckeditor then it is showing like this :

[image]

I have tried every solution which I could find on google but still no solution. Is there any solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today. I simply added the [Media Embed](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/mediaembed.html) plugin to ckeditor to make tweets work. Maybe someone will find this useful.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'embed';
```